# Invalid package type on majorupgrade of WiX bundle

Tags: wix

I have made with WiX 3.8 a boostrapper application in which the user can select between three different setup-types (workstation, client and server).
Installation, repair and uninstallation worked fine with the bootstrapper-engine-method Plan and the appropriate LaunchAction (Install, Repair, Uninstall).

Now i want to implement the majorupgrade-method.
In the UI-project (the surface for installation) i added a new method containing the following line:

```
    Plan(LaunchAction.UpdateReplace);
```

I install an older version of my setup and then i start a newer version of the setup (with a higher version number of course).
The newer setup detect the older one and inform the user, that there is an older installation and the user can click a button to upgrade it.
That's the point, when the plan-method will be called with LaunchAction.UpdateReplace.
But upgrade fails and i get the following log:

```
Burn v3.8.1128.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\experimente\Staffdirector\v4.81.1.0\ProsoftSetup.exe, cmdline: ''
Initializing string variable 'INSTALLFOLDER' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]'
Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\PATRIC~1.PRO\AppData\Local\Temp\Staffdirector_20141030102104.log'
Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\experimente\Staffdirector\v4.81.1.0\ProsoftSetup.exe'
Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Staffdirector'
Loading managed bootstrapper application.
Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
Detect begin, 9 packages
Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Sync Framework\v2.0\Setup\SynchronizationX64'
Setting string variable 'Netfx4FullVersion' to value '4.5.51641'
Setting string variable 'Netfx4x64FullVersion' to value '4.5.51641'
Setting string variable 'SyncX86' to value '1'
Detected related bundle: {b7d055e3-3c85-477c-ab04-206e964536f8}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 4.80.1.0, operation: MajorUpgrade
Condition 'Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)' evaluates to true.
Detected package: DotNetFramework_4_5_1, state: Present, cached: None
Detected package: WindowsInstaller45_WinXP_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: WindowsInstaller45_WinServer2003_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: WindowsInstaller45_WinServer2003_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: WindowsInstaller45_Win6_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: WindowsInstaller45_Win6_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: SynchronizationX64, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: SynchronizationX86, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: SetupPackage, state: Absent, cached: None
Detect complete, result: 0x0
Setting string variable 'IsWorkstationSetup' to value 'true'
Setting string variable 'INSTALLFOLDER' to value 'C:\Program Files (x86)'
Detect begin, 9 packages
Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Sync Framework\v2.0\Setup\SynchronizationX64'
Setting string variable 'Netfx4FullVersion' to value '4.5.51641'
Setting string variable 'Netfx4x64FullVersion' to value '4.5.51641'
Setting string variable 'SyncX86' to value '1'
Detected related bundle: {b7d055e3-3c85-477c-ab04-206e964536f8}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 4.80.1.0, operation: MajorUpgrade
RelatedBundleProductCode is {b7d055e3-3c85-477c-ab04-206e964536f8}
Condition 'Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)' evaluates to true.
Detected package: DotNetFramework_4_5_1, state: Present, cached: None
Detected package: WindowsInstaller45_WinXP_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: WindowsInstaller45_WinServer2003_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: WindowsInstaller45_WinServer2003_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: WindowsInstaller45_Win6_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: WindowsInstaller45_Win6_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: SynchronizationX64, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: SynchronizationX86, state: Absent, cached: None
Detected package: SetupPackage, state: Absent, cached: None
Detect complete, result: 0x0
Plan: method begins
Plan: Test UI.View == null is False
Plan: Do action UpdateReplace
Plan begin, 9 packages, action: UpdateReplace
OnPlanPackageBegin: method begins
OnPlanPackageBegin: PackageId = 
Invalid package type.
Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to plan execute package.
Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to process update package.
Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to plan update.
OnPlanComplete: method begins
OnPlanComplete: CurrentInstallationState = DetectedOlder
OnPlanComplete: Installation failed
OnPlanComplete: CurrentInstallationState = Failed
Plan complete, result: 0x8000ffff
Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
Variable: INSTALLFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)
Variable: IsWorkstationSetup = true
Variable: Netfx4FullVersion = 4.5.51641
Variable: Netfx4x64FullVersion = 4.5.51641
Variable: SyncX86 = 1
Variable: VersionNT64 = 6.3.0.0
Variable: WixBundleAction = 7
Variable: WixBundleElevated = 0
```

In the bundle itself i setted the product-id to asterisk, so it creates always a new GUID at build-time.
As You can see here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Staffdirector"
            Version="$(var.BuildVersion)"
            Manufacturer="MyFirm"
            UpgradeCode="DF43F081-B375-42EE-8139-0488254624E6"
            IconSourceFile="Images\icon.ico">

        <!-- Variables for the different setuptypes. These will be filled by the UI. -->
        <?define IsWorkstationSetup = "true" ?>
        <?define IsClientSetup = "false" ?>
        <?define IsServerSetup = "false" ?>

        <!-- Variable for the installerlocation. Can be filled by the UI. -->
        <Variable Name="INSTALLFOLDER"
                  bal:Overridable="yes"
                  Type="string"
                  Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]"/>

        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >
            <Payload Name='BootstrapperCore.config'
                     SourceFile='..\..\..\Prosoft.Setup.Installer.UI\bin\Debug\BootstrapperCore.config' />
            <Payload SourceFile='..\..\..\Prosoft.Setup.Installer.UI\bin\Debug\SetupInstallerUI.dll'/>

            <Payload SourceFile='..\..\..\Prosoft.Setup.UI\bin\Debug\Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll' />
            <Payload SourceFile='..\..\..\Prosoft.Setup.UI\bin\Debug\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.dll' />
            <Payload SourceFile='..\..\..\Prosoft.Setup.UI\bin\Debug\Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.dll' />
            <Payload SourceFile='..\..\..\Prosoft.Setup.UI\bin\Debug\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll' />
            <Payload SourceFile='..\..\..\Prosoft.Setup.UI\bin\Debug\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.dll' />
            <Payload SourceFile='..\..\..\Prosoft.Setup.UI\bin\Debug\Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView.dll' />
            <Payload SourceFile='..\..\..\Prosoft.Setup.UI\bin\Debug\Telerik.Windows.Data.dll' />
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
            <!-- In this package the variable WixMbaPrereqPackageId is defined. -->
            <PackageGroupRef Id='Ndp451Aiios' />

            <PackageGroupRef Id='WindowsInstaller45' />

            <!--<PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx4Full' />-->

            <PackageGroupRef Id='SyncFramework' />

            <?if $(var.IsServerSetup) = "true"?>
                <PackageGroupRef Id='SqlServerExpress' />
            <?endif?>

            <!-- Workstation-Setup -->
            <?if $(var.IsWorkstationSetup) = "true"?>
                <MsiPackage Id='SetupPackage'
                            SourceFile='.\Resources\Setup.msi'
                            Permanent='no'
                            Cache='yes'
                            DisplayInternalUI='no'
                            Vital='yes'
                            Compressed='yes'
                            EnableFeatureSelection='no'
                            DisplayName='ProsoftSetup'>
                    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION"
                                 Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" />
                </MsiPackage>
            <?endif?>

            <!-- TODO Client-Setup -->
            <?if $(var.IsClientSetup) = "true"?>
                <MsiPackage Id='SetupPackage'
                            SourceFile='.\Resources\Setup.msi'
                            Permanent='no'
                            Cache='yes'
                            DisplayInternalUI='no'
                            Vital='yes'
                            Compressed='yes'
                            EnableFeatureSelection='no'
                            DisplayName='ProsoftSetup'>
                    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION"
                                 Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" />
                </MsiPackage>
            <?endif?>

            <!-- TODO Server-Setup -->
            <?if $(var.IsServerSetup) = "true"?>
                <MsiPackage Id='SetupPackage'
                            SourceFile='.\Resources\Setup.msi'
                            Permanent='no'
                            Cache='yes'
                            DisplayInternalUI='no'
                            Vital='yes'
                            Compressed='yes'`enter code here`
                            EnableFeatureSelection='no'
                            DisplayName='ProsoftSetup'>
                    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION"
                                 Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" />
                </MsiPackage>
            <?endif?>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

That's the setup for workstation (Product.wxs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <?define Manufactor = "MyFirm"?>
    <?define UpgradeGuid = "694926FB-81DD-4531-93BE-EE227859584C"?>

    <Product Id="*"
             Name="MyApplication"
             Language="1031"
             Version="$(var.BuildVersion)"
             Manufacturer="$(var.Manufactor)"
             UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeGuid)"
             Codepage="UTF-8">

        <Package InstallerVersion="405"
                 Compressed="yes"
                 InstallScope="perMachine"/>

        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature"
                 Title="Prosoft.Setup.Msi"
                 Level="1" >
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="SourceComponentGroup"/>
            <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut"/>
        </Feature>

        <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON"
                  Value="Icon.exe"/>
        <Icon Id="Icon.exe"
              SourceFile="..\..\..\Bootstrapper\Images\icon.ico" />

    </Product>
    <Fragment Id="ClientFragment">
        <!-- Here the variable from the bootstrapper will be setted into INSTALLDIR. -->
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR"
                   Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION"
                           Name="InstallLocation">
                    <Directory Id="CompanyFolder"
                               Name="prosoft">
                        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR"
                                   Name="staffdirector" />
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="DesktopFolder"
                       Name="Desktop"/>

            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
                <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder"
                           Name="staffdirector">

                    <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut"
                               Guid="F8EE48A5-5264-4180-A35C-5CB7E8A0D58C">

                        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
                                  Name="staffdirector"
                                  Target="[INSTALLDIR]staffdirector.exe"
                                  WorkingDirectory="ProgramFolder"
                                  Icon="Icon.exe"/>

                        <Shortcut Id="StaffdirectorDesktopShortCut"
                                  Directory="DesktopFolder"
                                  Name="staffdirector"
                                  Target="[INSTALLDIR]staffdirector.exe"
                                  WorkingDirectory="InstallDirectory"
                                  Description="Startet den staffdirector"
                                  Icon="Icon.exe">
                        </Shortcut>

                        <RemoveFolder Id="INSTALLLOCATION"
                                      On="uninstall"/>

                        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
                                       Key="Software\Prosoft\staffdirector"
                                       Name="installed"
                                       Type="integer"
                                       Value="1"
                                       KeyPath="yes" />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Can anybody tell me, what's going wrong?
Please don't answer me, i shall use LauchAction.Install instead.
I did it and the result was an endless loop of installerwindows, which wanted to uninstall the application.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The correct action is `Install` not `UpdateReplace`.  `UpdateReplace` is when your bundle recognizes that there is a newer version of the bundle available and wants to exit and let the newer version run.  The error in your log is because your custom bootstrapper application didn't inform the engine about where the newer version is.

It sounds like you're running into [this issue](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/3890/), which was fixed in v3.9.  Either that, or your custom BA is not handling silent uninstall correctly.